# Prove that for a continuous function $q(t)\leq-1$ the boundary problem has only the trivial solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove that for a continuous function $q(t)\leq-1$ the boundary problem has only the trivial solution
> $x''(t)+q(t)x(t)=0,x(a)=0,\sqrt{3}x'(b)=x(b),a<b$

I Know that $q(t)\leq-1$ so I tried to solve $x''(t)-x(t)=0$ which I get $x(t)=c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^t$ and I got from the $x(a)=0,\sqrt{3}x'(b)=x(b)$ that $c_1,c_2=0$ but I don't think I've done this right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the whole situation so that $a=0$. As the equation and boundary conditions are homogeneous, scalar multiples of solutions are also solutions. Thus fix $x'(0)=1$. If $x$ had another root, it would also have a maximum $c$ where $x''(c)\le0<-q(c)x(c)$ which is impossible.

The obvious function to compare the solution $x(t)$ against is $\sinh(t)$. In the Liouville theory this is often done via a Wronski-like expression. Set
$$
w(t)=\cosh(t)x(t)-\sinh(t)x'(t).
$$
Then
$$
w'(t)=\sinh(t)(x(t)-x''(t))=\sinh(t)(1+q(t))x(t)\le 0
$$
which implies $w(t)\le w(0)=0$ and thus
$$
0<x(t)\le\tanh(t)x'(t)< x'(t)<\sqrt3 x'(t)
$$
Equality is thus never possible.

Comment: Can you explain this part please?it would also have a maximum c where $x′′(c)≤0<−q(c)x(c)$ which is impossible

Comment: Because $x''=-qx$ you would need that $x''$ is at the same time negative and positive, which is impossible. In general, if $q<0$, then any solution has at most one root.